# error while exporting neo4j to Graphml

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

I'm trying to export `Neo4j` graph (with `4318` nodes & `8145` Relationships) for testing using `gremlin-groovy-2.3.0` using:

```
  g = new Neo4jGraph('/tmp/mygraph');
  g.saveGraphML('mygraph.xml');
```

but getting list of errors when typing the 1st command in console (`gremlin-groovy-2.3.0/bin/gremlin.bat`), Last line of error:

```
Error:   Component: 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@5e1a7112 was successfully initialized, but failed to start
```

I have copied the `Neo4j` database (`\data\graph.db`) to `Gremli` (`gremlin-groovy-2.3.0/bin/tmp/mygraph`).

Sometimes it runs without error but then shows below error:
[image: gremlin graphdb to graphml]

how to export ?

Comment: i don't see an error in your screenshot.  also...if you've copied the database files of neo4j to `gremlin-groovy-2.3.0/bin/tmp/mygraph` then your path to the database is bad (pointed at the root of the file system) and you should do something like `new Neo4jGraph('bin/tmp/mygraph')`

Comment: still it is giving Null ?

Comment: `null` does not necessarily imply an error.  That is expected output as there is no return value of `saveGraphML`.  Indeed, a successful call to that method will show null to the REPL (check the location for where you wrote the file to and you should see `mygraph.xml` present.  I would expect an "error" to produce some stack trace to the REPL.

Comment: i have copied the folder (\neo4j-community-1.9\data\graph.db) to (gremlin-groovy-2.3.0\bin\tmp\mygraph) ....is this what i need to do ?

Comment: not sure that you need to copy it at all.  why not just point `Neo4jGraph` at the neo4j directory (assuming that you don't have the graph running in some other process)?  I assume that the `graph.db` directory has all the files that `Neo4jGraph` needs (but i'm not familiar with how Neo4j runs natively outside of Blueprints).

Comment: sir, how to "point Neo4jGraph at the neo4j directory" ?

Comment: i just mean that if your neo4j data is here: `\neo4j-community-1.9\data\graph.db` then make sure that neo4j is not running in some other process and open the graph from the gremlin prompt `g = new Neo4jGraph('\neo4j-community-1.9\data\graph.db')`