# Neo4j query results to Gephi

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, gephi

I have a Neo4j graph that I want to visualize using Gephi. I am able to import the whole graph using the Neo4j plugin, but I only want a visual for the nodes returned by a query:

```
START n=node(*)  
MATCH com<-[:ON_COMMITTEE]-n-[:HAS_OFFICE_IN]->x<-[:LOCATED_IN]-y<-[:AFFILIATED_WITH]-z<-[:WRITTEN_BY]-m  
WHERE com.name="Committee on Finance" or com.name="Financial Services"  
RETURN collect(com.name), com.house, n.name, x.name, y, y.name, collect(distinct z.name), m.title, m.published, m.times_cited
```

I have looked into getting the graph into Gremlin, but keep getting 
`groovysh_parse: 46: unexpected token: = @ line 46, column 6.` when I try and open my graph using this command:`$_g := neo4j:open('../gephiData/neo4j-community-1.9/data/graph.db')`

I also tried the traversal import, but it would never display anything when I tried it.

I am in no way tied to Gremlin, but can't seem to find anyway to get only the results that I want into Gephi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say I fully follow, but if you are executing this from the Gremlin REPL:

```
_g := neo4j:open('../gephiData/neo4j-community-1.9/data/graph.db')
```

you are likely getting that error because it isn't valid Gremlin.  The appropriate way to open a `Graph` is:

```
g = new Neo4jGraph('../gephiData/neo4j-community-1.9/data/graph.db')
```

As mentioned in the comments to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541166/error-while-exporting-neo4j-to-graphml) here, make sure that Neo4j is not running in some other process when you try to do this.

From there you could go about subgraphing to a `TinkerGraph` and saving that graph as GraphML.  You can see a bit more on the approach to subgraphing with Gremlin here:

http://gremlindocs.com/#recipes/subgraphing

Comment: Thanks so much! I saw several places on the web where they suggested the first way, but I could never get it to work. Yours did the trick!